# How can I identify a widget (frame) with some sort of ID?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to set an ID for each frame on a set of frame, in order to fill them with database information and keep track of which frame is linked with which database information. Here's an idea of what the set of frame will look like :

[image: frame]

What I need, for each of these frames, is to be able to recognize them. For example, we can consider that each frame represent a friend in a friendlist, if I click on one frame and press the delete button, I want to first delete the frame but of course delete the information related on the database, so delete this friend from my list, this is why I need to have an ID on the frame. (In the future, the delete button will be place ON the frame itself, so by clicking on it I will be able to get the parent widget).

In addition, each frame will contain multiple `QLabel`s ("One", "Two", "Three", "Four" in the picture above) and I need to be able to identify them as well, since they will represent database information which can be deleted like the frame. But one problem at a time.

I first thought about hiding a label which would contain the friend ID, but it seems like a bad idea.

I then thought about using a list and associate the frame with an ID, but when clicking on the frame, how will I be able to get back his position on the list ? The frame will have the same position among them on the list than on the window, but then I would need to get their position in the window, which I don't know how to do it.

I hope I'm clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since `QWidget` is a `QObject`, you can give them unique names (`QObject::setName`), or assign arbitrary QVariant-valued properties to them, a-la JavaScript (`QObject::setProperty`). This should allow you to easily keep track of what database fields are mapped to what widget. It's easy enough to add your custom type support to `QVariant`, see the documentation.

Alternately to dynamic properties, you can have a map between `QWidget*` and whatever data structure you need to describe the connection.

If you're using a data source through a `QAbstractItemModel`, then you can also use a [`QDataWidgetMapper`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html) to bind model's data to widgets.

You can also easily bind data from a model to items in QML.